# How to access a table present in a schema using persistent

Tags: postgresql, haskell, persistent

I have a database which has different schema for different tables.

Example

```
CREATE TABLE animals.dog
(
      id                        INTEGER
    , name                      CHARACTER VARYING(20)
    , year                      INTEGER
);
```

When I want to query the dog table, I want to access it directly, as if it was created by persistent.

The query created to access data is generated as `SELECT "id", "name", "year" FROM "animals.dog";` which assumes `.` to be part of table name.

Is there a way by which I can data from tables, present in some schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick review of the docs and a search through the bug tracker, this is not currently support in Persistent. See [bug #93](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/issues/93).